# How to insert HTML inside Javascript?

Tags: reactjs

Is this the correct way to insert HTML within IF ?

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
            {
              if (!error) {
                <p>Sorry - there was an error</p>
              }
              else {
                <p>{this.state.data}</p>
              }
            }
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [**multiple ways you can do this**](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), all are "correct" and or valid ways to do what you are trying to do. It really comes down to your code style and what is readable / makes sense for you... I'll add a few different ways to do this so you can see what I mean and decide what works best for you :)

Ternary operator for conditionals in jsx

```
<div>
    { error ? <p>Sorry - there was an error</p> : <p>{this.state.data}</p> }
</div>
```

inline if with logical `&&` (aka `short-circuit evaluation`)

```
<div>
    { error && <p>Sorry - there was an error</p> }
    { !error && <p>{this.state.data}</p> }
</div>
```

another way is to use the if's outside of the return.

```
render() {
  const {error} = this.props
  const {data} = this.state
  if (error) {
    return <p>Sorry - there was an error</p>
  }
  return <p>{data}</p>
}
```

Comment: The "logical `&&`" is called a short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: @Chris Yep thanks for clarifying. I titled it that to follow [**what the react docs say**](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator) so its easier to see the example and what its referencing. I'll update to include the correct technical term though! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, inside the render method , you can do something like :

```
if(condition) {
return(your html)
} 
else {
return(another html)
}
```